# Conditionals within channel form custom_fields loop?

Tags: safecracker, conditionals

Trying to setup a public submission page/form using channel:form in ExpressionEngine 6.3.4, and the relevant channel has some fields that the user shouldn't be able to fill in/edit themselves, as I'll be putting those in the template as hidden fields instead.

In the past (mainly with EE 2.x) I've been able to do things like this to hide fields that I didn't output by the custom_fields loop :

```
{custom_fields}
    {if "{field_name}" != "hiddenfieldname"}
    [CODE TO OUTPUT THE FIELDS GOES HERE]
    {/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

But when I try to do the same thing in EE 6.3.4, it doesn't work as intended - and the conditional tags themselves are showing up in the output, with an odd EE template comment ahead of each one (which doesn't exist in the template code), E.g.

{!-- ra:000000000aba49ff000000005af6a0c9 --}{if 'fieldname1' == 'hiddenfieldname'}
Field Label:
[field]
{/if}

Any ideas how to get around that, or is that a technique that no longer works in newer versions of EE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding show_fields="not hiddenfieldname" to your channel field tag.  you can show and hide fields in the tag.